# Xcode 9: Getting More Information On Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

After learning that a memory leak may be the cause of my iOS app crashing hours after being installed onto my phone, I've watched and read videos/articles surrounding memory leaks, specifically in Xcode and how to debug them. I've been trying to use the Memory Debugger and Xcode leaks instrument with no luck. I am wondering, how do I find the source of my leaks? The screenshot I attached shows one of the many leaks and it never lets me dig deeper than what the picture shows. In videos, Xcode takes them to the line of code causing the issue using the backtrace, however I have not been able to do that in any of the cases. I am also noticing the leaks are coming from the UIKIT, is this normal? Appreciate any help as I am fairly new to Xcode.

[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an2hC.png)

Here is some code from my initial log in view controller. In the second image you'll see that the only view that has a memory leak is this one, however - I can't dig deeper on this either. 
[Second image of memory leak from InitialLogInVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKciv.png)

```
import UIKit

class IntialLoginInViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundAlbumArt: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foregroundAlbumArt: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var musicNameLabel: UILabel!
    private weak var imageOne = UIImage(named: "taste.jpg")
    private weak var imageTwo = UIImage(named: "NavReckless.jpg")
    private weak var imageThree = UIImage(named: "watch.jpg")
    private weak var imageFour = UIImage(named: "juicewrld.jpg")

    lazy var imageInformation = [(name:"Taste - Tyga", image:imageOne),(name:"Reckless - Nav", image: imageTwo),(name:"Watch - Travis Scott", image: imageThree), (name:"Goodbye & Good Riddance - Juice Wrld", image: imageFour)]
    private var currentIndex = 0
    static var spotifySession: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        foregroundAlbumArt.image = imageOne
        backgroundAlbumArt.image = imageOne
        musicNameLabel.text = imageInformation[0].name
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(imageRefresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @objc func imageRefresh(){
        if currentIndex == imageInformation.count - 1 {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
        else {
            currentIndex += 1
        }
        //Update Label
        UIView.transition(with: self.musicNameLabel, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: {
            self.musicNameLabel.text = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].name

        }, completion: nil)
        //Update foreground Album
        UIView.transition(with: self.foregroundAlbumArt, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: {
            self.foregroundAlbumArt.image = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].image
        }, completion: nil)
        //Update background Album

        UIView.transition(with: self.backgroundAlbumArt, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: {
            self.backgroundAlbumArt.image = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].image
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: If you know which controller or view is causing the leak, you can post some code and we can examine.. So far, it seems like a storyboard issue

Comment: @Brandon I have added code from the initial log in view controller. I am not 100% if this is the cause, however it is the only view that appears in the memory leaks warnings.

Comment: You are leaking a `Timer`.. which keeps a retain on `self` aka the Target. You need to keep a reference to it and inside `viewWillDisappear` you need to call `timerReference.invalidate()`. Other than that, I see no leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    //Update Label
    UIView.transition(with: self.musicNameLabel, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.musicNameLabel.text = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].name

    }, completion: nil)

    //Update foreground Album
    UIView.transition(with: self.foregroundAlbumArt, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.foregroundAlbumArt.image = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].image
    }, completion: nil)
    //Update background Album

    UIView.transition(with: self.backgroundAlbumArt, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve] , animations: { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.backgroundAlbumArt.image = self.imageInformation[self.currentIndex].image
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This worked! I believe this, along with what Brandon suggested solved my problem. Do you have any suggestions on where I could learn when to use [weak self] in my code? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can check this article: https://medium.com/anysuggestion/preventing-memory-leaks-with-swift-compile-time-safety-49b845df4dc6 , glad to help ;)